# window.getComputedStyle(elem) for the case where the element is not hovered, even though it is currently hovered

Tags: javascript, css

I have several elements whose height increases slightly when they are hovered. Upon clicking one of them, I need to get the hight of that element when it is NOT hovered.

`window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).height` gives me the hovered height. Same with `window.getComputedStyle(elem, ':not(:hovered)').height`.

The difference between normal height and hovered height is unfortunately not constant, so I can't just subtract that constant.

Edit: Added a minimal working example:

```js
function onClick(target) {
  const hoveredHeight = window.getComputedStyle(target, ':hovered').height;
  const normalHeight = window.getComputedStyle(target, null).height;
  
  alert('The hovered height is ' + hoveredHeight + ', and the normal height is ' + normalHeight);
}
```

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#hover-me {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: height 0.1s linear;
}

#hover-me:hover {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="hover-me" onclick="onClick(this)"><p>Click me</p></div>
```

Comment: What is your purpose of getting the **not hovered** height?

Comment: A kind of tooltip appears when one of the elements are clicked. I need to know exactly where to position that tooltip. As soon as the element is no longer hovered, the tooltip appears out of position.

Comment: Can you post your question using **code snippet** feature of stackkoverflow.

Comment: I've added a code snippet @ChickenSoups.

Comment: Why don't you make the tooltip absolute and apply `top:0;left:0;` so it's always on the top even if the height changes

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **:hovered** is invalid option to **window.getComputedStyle()** function because **:hovered** is not a [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Use_with_pseudo-elements) but a [pseudo-classes](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp).

So your sentence `window.getComputedStyle(target, ':hovered').height` have the same result with `window.getComputedStyle(target).height` or any value you passed into second parameter place.

If you want to store your element's height before hover, you have many way. I demo one way using javascript and **onmouseenter** and **onmouseleave** event in my snippet code.

```js
var originalHeight;
function onClick(target) {
  const currentHeight = window.getComputedStyle(target).height;
  alert('The hovered height is ' + currentHeight + ', and the normal height is ' + originalHeight);
}

function onMouseEnter(target) {
    originalHeight = window.getComputedStyle(target).height;
    // set new height
    target.style.height = '100px';
}

function onMouseLeave(target) {
    // reset the original height
    target.style.height = originalHeight;
}
```

```css
p {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#hover-me {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #999;
  vertical-align: middle;
  transition: height 0.1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="hover-me" onclick="onClick(this)" onmouseenter="onMouseEnter(this)" onmouseleave="onMouseLeave(this)"><p>Click me</p></div>
```